# Convert an X,Y pair into a unique reverse-able number

Tags: php, numbers, unique

Assume you have coordinate pairs Xn,Yn how would you convert the pair into a unique reverse-able number such that for any such series Yn * Xn != Xn * Yn?

Right now I use the multiplication method to get one number; however, this causes problems because for any series like 1600,2000  2000,1600 results in the same non unique number.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/ As it stands, you want `3 * 2 != 2 * 3`? Unpossible!

Comment: It is not homework, it is an computer screen x,y issue. The screen resolution idea might work, let me try that.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not math homework.

Comment: Well Marc B good to know when you program you never use math. Must be really interesting programs. In any case, the screen resolution idea worked rather well. Thank you Mr. Lister.

Comment: OK, I'll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the address of a pixel on a computer screen in a single number, the most efficient way would be to multiply Y by the number of horizontal pixels. With a horizontal resolution of 1280, the top row will have numbers 0 through 1279, the second row 1280 through 2559, and so on. In fact, this is how the computers themselves do it. (*)

But if you want to use the same formula for different computer monitors, it's best to not rely on the horizontal resolution, but to use a large constant value for the multiplication factor, so that the calculations become more efficient.
For 32 bits integers, 2<sup>16</sup> is a nice number; this allows for resolutions of up to 65536 × 65536. (Of course if you're trying to print posters, you may have to grow to a bigger scale.)

```c
 number = (Y<<16)+X;
```

and to reverse

```c
 X = number&65535; Y = number>>16;
```

(*) That's an oversimplification, but you get the idea.